# Count number of ocorrences with regex

Tags: java, regex, file

How can I count the number of words (strings) in a text with a certain pattern?

```
public static int matches(File file, Pattern p) {

    int count = 0;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file) );
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line  != null) {
             String[] vs = line.split(" ");
             for(String s : vs){
                 if(s.equals(p)){ // the problem is here
                     count++;
                     }
                 line = reader.readLine();
             }
    return count;
      }
```

And how can I count the number of times a certain pattern occurs in a word (string)?

```
public static int matchesString(String s, Pattern p)  {
       I have no ideia how to do this method...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `matcher.find()`, maybe

Comment: If you are looking for `aa` then in `aaa` does it occurs one or twice?

Comment: do you want to count the number of times the pattern is matched in the input?

Comment: @Pshemo i think it's occurs twice

Comment: @Bohemian yes! I have no ideia how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first snippet you can use `String.matches(String regex)` instead of the `equals` method -

```
if(s.matches(regexString)) {  //regexString is a string not an Pattern instance
```

---

For the second, you can use the `Matcher` class -

```
int count = 0;
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    count++;
}
return count;
```

Comment: For the first snippet can i do something like this: s.matches(p.toString())? p is a Pattern instance,I didn't understand the part of regexString

Comment: I mean the regular expression string that you use to create the `Pattern` instance like - `Pattern.compile(regexString)`. The `Pattern.pattern()` method returns that string. But I don't know why you would that Pattern in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex and word boundaries you can get # of occurrences of a word in a line using:

```
int count = line.split("\\b" + word + "\\b").length -1;
```